# Security Error in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas, svg, highcharts

I have an highchart(svg) i am trying to covert this as an image base64 format. In chrome its working fine in IE11(throwing security Error)

```
  highchartsExport.nativeSVGtoImage($("#highchartcontainer").find("svg")[0],function(uri){
                    var data = $.param({'dataURL': uri, 'emailContent': $scope.content});
                    var config = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/pdf;'}}
```

In highchartsExport:

```
 exp.nativeSVGtoImage = function(DOMObject,callback,format){
            if(!DOMObject.nodeName){
                throw new error("Se requiere un objeto DOM de tipo SVG. Obtener con document.getElementById o un selector de jQuery $(contenedor).find('svg')[0]");
            }

            var svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(DOMObject);
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = $(DOMObject).width();
            canvas.height = $(DOMObject).height();
            var ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
            var img = new Image();//document.createElement("img");
            img.setAttribute( "src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgData))) );
            img.onload = function() {
                ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );

                 if(format === "jpeg" || format === "jpg"){
                     callback(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
                 }else{
                     callback(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                 }
            }; 
            return true;
        };
```

But its throwing Security Error i tried to set cross-origin but still same error

Comment: What is the security error? Can you make a proof of concept showing the error in jsfiddle or similar?

Comment: When coming to this line :    callback(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));   SCRIPT5022: SecurityError
File: highchartexport.js, Line: 55, Column: 21 
                                                                               @Halcyon

Comment: when drawing an svg on the canvas using drawImage method, IE < Edge does taint the canvas. Only workaround : reproduce the svg using only canvas drawing methods. a library like canvg can help.